# assembly x86 Using stack's value as pointer?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I wonder how do I have to pass pointer argument to procedure?

I have to create function who have 2 arguments:

1. words array
2. array's size

The function gets array that the array's size and sum the column.

That's what I've coded:

```
.MODEL  Small
.STACK  64

; +===============================+
; |             DATA              |
; +===============================+

.DATA 
array1      dw  1,2,3,4
array1size  dw  4
result      dw  ?
address     dw  ?
; print
TMP     dw  0 ; general temporary variable ..
.code

addNumbers proc
;   reset result
    lea di,result
;   use stack
    mov bp,sp
;   get num array
    mov bx,[bp+2]
;   get num of numbers
    mov cx,[bp+4]
; making additiontion
adding:
    add [di],bx
    inc bx; go to the next bx
loop adding
    ret 2
endp

; start
start:
    mov ax,@DATA
    mov ds,ax
; set strings
    push array1size
    push offset array1
    call addNumbers
; print
    mov dx:ax,result
    call printNumber
    mov ah,4ch
    mov al,0
    int 21H
end start
```

the problem - it's adding to result the offset pointer (here is `cs:0000`,`cs:0001`,`cs:0002`,`cs:0003`) and not the offset value (here is: `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`).

Because of this, result will be 6 and not 10.

could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INC BX
```

will of course add 1 (byte) to the pointer in BX. If you need to move one WORD, you have to add the size of the word. Say that is 2 bytes, then you need

```
ADD BX, 2
```

instead of the `INC`.

Your other problem is that you don't add the values pointed-to, `[BX]`, but the pointers themselves `BX`. You might use a spare register, like `AX` to compute the sum.

```
    MOV  AX,0
adding:
    ADD  AX,[BX]
    ADD  BX,2
    LOOP adding
    MOV  [result],AX

    RET  4
```